# Ubuntu 18.04 does not work smoothly

Tags: boot, video

When I was using version 17.04, as I remember everything was OK. Then, after upgrading to 17.10, online videos were chopped, the frames stuck meanwhile rest of videos was played forward. This also included HD videos on local discs (.mkv or .mp4). So i upgraded to 18.04, hoping now it would be better, but unfortunately it is even worse. Absolutely no video plays smoothly, what is more even websites with a lot of stuff load long when I try to scroll them down (e.g. Facebook fanpages etc). Perhaps, one of the reason may be that i need to log in to the system via recovery mode, because normal boot also does not work (the boot screen freezes while Ubuntu logo is on).

The data about my Dell laptop:
Intel® Celeron(R) M CPU 430 @ 1.73GHz
llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)
GNOME: 3.28.1
32-bits

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You'll need to use a less resource consuming flavor like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Your processor is more than 10 years old. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_microprocessors#%22Conroe-L%22_(65_nm) You should check [lighter Ubuntu flavours](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/250300).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 Your CPU doesn't meet minimum recommended CPU frequency 2 GHz. From 17.10 onwards the desktop uses GNOME Shell. In order to run these environments the system needs a more capable graphics adapter with 4096 MiB RAM and 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB.

Comment: Following up to this, you might give Lubuntu or Xubuntu a try -- they are somewhat less demanding (and not just in terms of "lighter" default applications; they also have lower resource demand in the desktop).